# append jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am creating a search suggestion and i want to create a div and put suggestion elements like full name, image and ... in it.
so i have a empty div in my HTML code that my suggestions will be added to it.

```
<input type="text" name="query" autocomplete="off" id="base_main_search_box">
<button type="button" value="" id="base_main_search_box_button"></button>
<div id="main_searchSuggestion">

</div>
```

i want to appear search suggestions when user key up in input type.
so i create jQuery function.
my jQuery function is:

```
$('#base_main_search_box').keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({url:'http://localhost:8000/search_suggestion/',success:function(result){
            $(addSuggestion).append('<div class="base_searchSuggestionItem">' +
                '<img src="' + result.movie_images[i] + '" class="base_searchSuggestionItem_image">' +
                '<div class="base_searchSuggestionItem_info">' +
                    '<p class="base_searchSuggestionItem_info_name">' +
                        '<a href="">' +
                            result.movie_names[0] +
                        '</a>' +
                        '(' +
                        result.movie_yearProduction[0] +
                        ')' +
                    '</p>' +
                    '<p class="base_searchSuggestionItem_info_description">' +
                        result.movie_descriptions[0] +
                    '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>');
            console.log('final: '+addSuggestion.innerHTML);
        }
    }});
});
```

the output is:

```
"final: undefined"
```

it is not correct.

Comment: Why are you complicating so much when you can just build it in the easy way? Don't mix vanilla JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: you need to add search_item to the dom first

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

`.html()` is not available on XML documents so you need to add it to DOM before setting or checking its HTML.

change the sequence as following

```
        $(addSuggestion).append(search_item);
        $(search_item).html(
            div_innerHTML
        );
        console.log('div_innerHTML: '+div_innerHTML);
        console.log('search_item: '+$(search_item).innerHTML);
```

Comment: @hamid what do you mean? what output did it gave?

Comment: i want to add search_item to addSuggestion as a child.

Comment: But what output did you got?

Comment: i edit my question and try it by append but it does not work too. i wrote my output at the end of question

Comment: It should be addSuggestion[0].innerHTML

Comment: in my page in addSuggestion div is undefined[object HTMLDivElement] i do not care about console but in page does not work

Comment: So what is the output when you do addSuggestion[0].innerHTML?

Comment: Or simply  addSuggestion.html()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106269/discussion-between-hamid-and-gurvinder372).